# Where to "destroy" Handlers in VB.NET classes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling, addhandler

I have some class (a user control) `MyUserControl` that rises events.

I use it in a form `MyForm`, in that, for some reasons I am forced to use `AddHandler` instead of `WithEvents<>Handles` pair.

I use `AddHandler`s in the `MyForm_Load` method.

Now. Adding handler is OK, the question now is where to remove this handler. Should it be done in the `Finalize` method of MyForm?   à la

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
  RemoveHandler _myCtrl.Action1Performed, AddressOf MyControl_Action1Performed  
  RemoveHandler _myCtrl.Action2Performed, AddressOf MyControl_Action2Performed  
  RemoveHandler _myCtrl.Action3Performed, AddressOf MyControl_Action3Performed  
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you expect that the lifespan of the form will be substantially longer than the lifespan of the user control? That is, are you dynamically adding and removing the user control without disposing the form itself?

Comment: @Cody Gray: actually not. The same lifetime as the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the container control (such as your form) is disposed, all of its event handlers will be automatically removed and disposed. This cleanup happens for you automatically because neither your user control nor its container form exist anymore.

The only time you really need to worry about calling `RemoveHandler` is if you're hooking up event handlers to objects that are expected to have a significantly longer lifespan than their containers. In that case, it's possible to create a memory leak because that object cannot be garbage collected as long as that handler is subscribed. You can read a much more comprehensive case study [here on Tess Ferrandez's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/23/net-memory-leak-case-study-the-event-handlers-that-made-the-memory-baloon.aspx?PageIndex=3). This is not a problem if both objects go "out of scope" at the same time.

**EDIT:** If you still feel that you absolutely need to remove the handler (perhaps you're obsessive compulsive?), you can go ahead and do it in the form's `Dispose` method. A purist might balk at the use of `IDisposable` for something like this, but you won't see any ill results. You do want to make sure that you don't implement the `Finalize` method for  this, though. There's just no point: the finalizer method won't get called until there are no more strong references to the object, but the only *possible* harm in failing to call `RemoveHandler` is that a container will hold onto a reference to that object longer than necessary. You're fooling yourself by trying to remove event handlers in the `Finalize` method.

Also keep in mind that it really doesn't matter *where* exactly you do it, because the purpose of `AddHandler`/`RemoveHandler` is to allow you to add and remove event handlers *dynamically*. You're allowed to call them anywhere in your code that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Form is the owner of the UserControl(s), you don't need any cleanup at all.

If you had handlers like `AddressOf OtherObject.Action1Performed` and OtherObject lives longer than the Form, then you should remove the handler.

---

#### Edit:

About the 'where' : **Not** in a `Sub Finalize` .

You can use the Dispose() method (in C# you can move it from the Designer file). Otherwise, use the FormClosed event.

A finalizer is not needed here, but it does come with considerable costs.

Comment: Anyway, to be sure I would like to remove them, just in case. So, the question is not about should I or not, but where :)

Comment: MSDN tells me that: `Note that even when you provide explicit control by way of Dispose, you should provide implicit cleanup using the Finalize method. Finalize provides a backup to prevent resources from permanently leaking if the programmer fails to call Dispose.`

Comment: If a control gets disposed, all childcontrols will also get disposed as well

Comment: MSDN is right when it is about _unmanaged_ resources. Controls are managed resources. No need for a finalizer. As @dkson stated.

Comment: @Henk: "Controls are managed resources." if controls are third party controls, neverknow.

Comment: @serhio: Yes I do know. If they are "Control" then they're not unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you removing the handlers, unless you are no longer needing them on the next post back and you conditionally set them again on page load, otherwise if you are using them for each post back, you should just let the GC handle the disposal

Comment: I used to remove handlers after some sophisticated problems with Infragistics controls memory leaks, caused by "keeping" disposed objects in the memory via event handlers.

Comment: in that case remove them right after the events in the page life cycle, which will be the Rendering, so in Prerender would be fine

Comment: or you can do it on closing or closed

Answer (score 0):

An object's finalizer will be useless for cleaning up that object's event subscriptions. It won't fire until all the publishers of all the events to which the object subscribes have gone out of scope themselves, and once that has happened the issue of cleaning up the events will become moot. Creating a finalizer for this purpose will actually be counter-productive since a finalizable object will delay the garbage-collection of itself and any object to which it holds a direct or indirect reference.

I would consider it a good practice to clean up event subscriptions as a matter of habit.  While one might regard event subscriptions as a managed resource if the publisher and subscriber have equal lifetimes, *events from long-lived objects are an unmanaged resource*.  They should be cleaned up in Dispose if they're not cleaned up elsewhere (and Dispose should be a 'back-stop' to cleanup elsewhere).  While one can get away with ignoring event subscriptions for short-lived objects, such a practice requires identifying which event publishers are, or may be, long-lived.  Note also that routinely unsubscribing from events when objects go out of scope will limit the damage that can be caused if an occasional event is missed.  If events from supposedly-short-lived objects are abandoned, but one long-lived object's event is abandoned as well, none of the short-lived objects may become eligible for garbage collection until the long-lived one does.